# Is there any way I can track down what is removing the executable flag from a file?

Tags: files, permissions

I have a set of git hooks that **constantly** have their executable flag removed. I'm utterly at a loss for what might be doing it, but so far the only thing I've found that can even mitigate the problem somewhat is to have `chmod +x ~/.git_template/hooks/*` in my `.bashrc` file (it's almost always gone when I've rebooted the computer). Barring putting that in my `PS1` function I'm running out of ideas and I'm wondering if there's anything to do with my particular set up that might be causing this or whether there's any way I can find out what process is causing this.

All my git repositories are created based on the template `~/.git_template` which just holds a symbolic link to the hooks directory I use (so they're all using up to date versions). While it might not be completely straight-forward, I don't see anything in this that should cause this kind of (frankly) baffling behaviour.

Edit: In fact, I've noticed since adding a new hook (`post-checkout`) that all hooks have their executable permission removed **every time** this hook is executed (at least so far). Just in case this might be relevant, I'll paste the full git hook here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var providedArguments = process.argv.slice(2)
var previousHead = providedArguments[0];
var newHead = providedArguments[1];

var changed = false;
var git = spawn('git', ['diff', previousHead, newHead, '--stat', '--', 'package.json']);
git.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    changed = true;
});
git.on('exit', function() {
    if (changed) {
        console.log('package.json changed. Running npm install');
        spawn('npm', ['install'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
    }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend trying `inotifywait -m ~/.git_template` and trying to see when something changes the mode of one of the files (an `ATTRIB` event). Unfortunately, it looks like there's no way to get the PID of the process that caused the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would run `strace -fo strace.log` or the equivalent on your system if not Linux (like `truss` on Solaris, `tusc` on HP/UX, `dtruss` on OS/X...) on the command that (eventually) calls that hook.

Then, in `strace.log`, you would be able to see what does the `chmod()` (or `fchmod()` or `fchmodat()`...), and follow the thread of `execve()`s to see what caused the files permissions to be modified.

Comment: For Mac OSX users, the equivalent is `dtruss`

Comment: @CharlesAddis, yes (added in), though in my little experience, `dtruss` on OS/X doesn't work properly if you're not superuser so can be cumbersome to use if you want to trace a command running as a normal user.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I'll give that a go when I get to the machine in question. Thanks!